# VERTICA SQL: Json in vchar column not loading properly into Flex Table

Tags: sql, json, vertica, flextable

I have a varchar column in a Vertica Table that stores data in JSON format. I am trying to copy this column into a FLEXTABLE so that I can map the columns from the JSON.

The varchar column in one of my regular tables that has json data like so:

```js
{
  "user"=>"x",
  "newPortfolio"=>"false",
  "tickers_added"=>"["BRK.A", "BA", "MORN", "VITSX"]",
  "tickers_already_in_portfolio"=>"[]",
  "rta"=>"true"
}
```

I called this column "try".

I created a Flex Table (`dwh.try_flex`), and then copied "try" into the Flex Table:

```
INSERT INTO dwh.try_flex SELECT try FROM temp_table;
```

The problem I'm running into is that "try" is now my Key, and the values is the JSON string in the try column.

How can I parse the json from the try column into the flex table properly?

Comment: What is the expected result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 2):

Flex tables are powered by a special column called `__raw__`, which contains a VMap, a map-like data structure. Most flex table operations are simply syntactic sugar for functions that operate on a VMap. VMaps aren't a data type in the normal database sense; they are more dynamic. Any string-like column with the right encoding can be treated as a VMap. Importantly, the VMap encoding is not JSON; it is a binary encoding that is organized for fast key search. That said, there are ways to bridge between the two formats.

There's a few problems with your approach. The database doesn't know you've put JSON into your VARCHAR column, and furthermore, your JSON string is not the VMap encoding required by flex tables. Finally, flex tables have special INSERT semantics to enable schema-on-read that you haven't adhered to.

To convert JSON text to a VMap, you can use the `MapJSONExtractor()` function. This takes JSON as input and returns a VMap. Try running:

`SELECT MapJSONExtractor(try) FROM temp_table`

The output is unintelligible binary -- this is the flex VMap encoding. Various flex functions operate on this encoding, including the reverse operation, `MapToString()`, which converts a VMap back to a JSON-like structure.

If you run:

`SELECT MapToString(MapJSONExtractor(try)) FROM temp_table`

You'll get JSON output again, but it may not look exactly the same as what you started with because it's been encoded & decoded again by Vertica. You don't need `MapToString()` to solve your problem, but it can be handy when trying to explore and understand data kept in a VMap.

Once you've converted your 'try' JSON column to a VMap with `MapJSONExtractor()`, you have to get it into your flex table. To do so you must understand a little bit about the magic behind flex tables.

When you do a read on a column in a flex table, Vertica first checks to see if a real column (real as in, a column defined with create table/projection DDL and kept in Vertica's traditional columnar storage) exists in the table. If it does, then you get the data for that column, just like a regular table column reference.

More importantly, if the column doesn't exist, that column reference is replaced with a call to `MapLookup()`. The map lookup searches for the key in the map, and if it exists the data for that column is returned. The value returned from a map lookup is either another VMap (an array is a map with integer keys), a string representing a scalar value, or NULL if the key wasn't present.

When you select a table, you can either select specific columns, or `*` to reference all columns. Selecting `*` is interesting for flex tables, because what does "all columns" mean? Maps in different rows may have different columns. It is semantically weird and would be prohibitively expensive to search the entire data set for columns, so Vertica only returns the real columns, including the `__raw__` VMap, in response to a `select *`.

A similar reconciliation happens when you insert. An unqualified insert without a column list inserts into "all columns". What does all columns mean in this context? Unlike the select case, we have some context available from the data being inserted. So Vertica will first attempt to match the data you provide with real columns. Any columns left over get coalesced into a VMap and inserted into `__raw__`.

With all that in mind, let's go back to your example:

`INSERT INTO dwh.try_flex SELECT try FROM temp_table;`

You've selected a column 'try' that has JSON data, but to Vertica is merely a string.

If try_flex had a real column called 'try', you're effectively running something like this:

`INSERT INTO dwh.try_flex(try, __raw__) VALUES temp_table.try, EmptyMap())`

If try_flex, had no column called 'try', then you'd be doing:

`INSERT INTO dwh.try_flex(__raw__) VALUES MapPut(EmptyMap(), temp_table.try USING PARAMETERS keys=SetMapKeys('try'))`

Breaking that down a bit:

- `MapPut()` writes a stream of values to the VMap in the first argument, which we have initialized to an empty VMap via `EmptyMap()`.
- The stream of values is a string, the raw data from your 'try' column (*not* a VMap).
- The key for the value stream is specified by SetMapKeys().

So, your problem is that you've inserted a string-containing-JSON, not a VMap, into the table.

What you want instead is something like:

`INSERT INTO dwh.try_flex SELECT MapJSONExtractor(try) FROM temp_table`

This would under the covers run something like:

`INSERT INTO dwh.try_flex(__raw__) VALUES MapPut(EmptyMap(), MapJSONExtractor(temp_table.try) using parameters keys=SetMapKeys('try'))`

When you go to query your flex table, it has a properly encoded VMap derived from your JSON column. Now that it is in this form, you can query the map like a table and get all the schema-on-read goodness that flex tables provide.

**Disclaimer:** I haven't tried running these examples myself so they may be slightly incorrect. Hopefully with this deeper understanding, and the flex table function reference in the documentation, you'll be able to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the MapJSONExtractor function.

https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/FlexTables/MAPJSONEXTRACTOR.htm

It takes a varchar and produces a VMap, which can then be used the same way as a `__raw__` record in a flex table.

To clarify, with this approach you won't be using a flex table at all - just extract the necessary fields from the VMap and insert them into a regular table.